# fetching giphy from api and displaying particular giphy in model view

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api

I am fetching Giphy from api and displaying all results. I want to make each giphy clickable and on clicking it appears in model view.

```
    var input = $("#search").val();
    var xhr = $.get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search? 
    q='"+input+"'&api_key=2MjLdox7zVRJXoXqKgy7tchbv07hfx2Z&limit=30");
    xhr.done(function(data) { console.log("success got data", data);
    var jiffs = data.data;

    for(i in jiffs)
    {
        var add = jiffs[i].images.original.url;  
        $('#inner').append("<img src ='"+jiffs[i].images.original.url+"' 
     style='height:300px; width:300px;'/>")

    }
    });
     }
```